# How to get the full Fourier spectrum in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft

I created a 6-bit quantizer and passed a signal through it, but when I plot the DFT, it peaks at 200 MHz and then stops; I'm not seeing the whole spectrum. What's preventing me in my code from getting the rest of the points at the higher frequencies?

Here is my code:

```
bits = 6; %6-bit
fs = 400e6; %sampling frequency
amp = 1; %amplitude
f = 200e6; %actual frequency
vpp = 2; peak-to-peak voltage
LSB = vpp/(2^bits); %least-significant bit
cycles = 1000;
duration = cycles/f;
values = 0:1/fs:duration;
party = LSB:LSB:(vpp-LSB); %partition
blocker = 0:1:(2^bits - 1); %codebook
biblocker = fliplr(decimaltobinary(blocker)); %I created a function that converts decimal to binary
qtone = amp + amp*sin(2*pi*f*values); %tone
[index, q] = quantization(qtone,party,blocker); %I created a quantizing function
ftq = fft(q)/length(q);                                         % Fourier Transform (Scaled)
qf = linspace(0, 1, fix(length(q))/2+1)*(fs/2);                     % Frequency Vector
qi = 1:length(qf);                                      % Index Vector
qa = abs(ftq(qi))*2/.7562;
figure
plot(qf/1e6, qa)                                % One-Sided Amplitude Plot
xlim([100 500]);
xlabel('Frequency [MHz]')
ylabel('Amplitude')
```

Here is what I get:

[image: partial Fourier spectrum]

Comment: It seems to me that you are plotting half your samples, if you are expecting higher frequencies, maybe you're computing `qf` wrong? You do have a typo: `fix(length(q))/2+1` should be `fix(length(q)/2)+1`. But it seems that `linspace` doesn't care it's not a round value.

Comment: @CrisLuengo It was the qf! Changed it to qf = linspace(0, 1, fix(length(q)))*(fs); Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since you selected your sampling frequency, fs = 400e6 i.e. 400 MHz, you can only observe the spectrum up to 200e6, half of the sampling frequency. You can read the theory behind it using Nyquist Sampling Theorem.

As a solution you need to set your twice the frequency you want to observe on the spectrum. It is impossible to observe whole frequency, you need to set a finite frequency limit.

Answer (score 1):

For base-band sampled data, everything in the spectrum above half the sample rate is redundant, just aliases for the spectrum below half the sample rate.  So there's no need to display the same spectrum repeated.

When sampling for a finite length of time (less than the age of the Earth, etc.), you have to sample at a rate **higher** than twice the highest frequency in the signal.  2X (400Msps for a 200MHz signal) often won't work.

Comment: "often" -> "never". The Nyquist frequency is aliased with the 0 frequency. A fraction of the power at that frequency is seen as the DC component, how large this fraction is depends on the phase.

Comment: Depending on the allowed error bounds, a perfect cosine wave exactly integer periodic in DFT/sampling aperture might work, depending on phase and sampling jitter.  Unlikely, but possible synthetically.

Comment: a perfect cosine gives the exact phase where 100% of the power goes to the Nuquist frequency and 0% gets aliased. But if you shift if even slightly you start to get aliasing. In any real-world situation, you won't be able to synchronize the signal with the sampling system well enough to not see any aliasing.

Comment: Also, the sine component (at or near fs/2)  doesn’t alias with DC. It aliases with its own complex conjugate which causes self cancelation.

Comment: That is true. Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

```
qf = linspace(0, 1, fix(length(q)))*(fs);
```

[image]

Comment: if your fs is 400MHz, then nothing above 200MHz should be legit- only harmonics and mirrors  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency)